# How to update new downloadable product attachment for placed orders in magento

Tags: magento, download, magento-1.7

I have downloadable products in my magento store.
My downloadable products are paid software tools.
We have update these downloadable software tools based on every version changes and enhancing new features in software tools.

Software package is ready for download, when the customers complete every successful payment transaction.

My Question is :

```
Version - 1:
```

Customers will purchase and use the `Version - 1` packages for `order id #101`.

```
Version - 2:
```

When we update `Version - 2` in admin panel for corresponding products. we need to place 
`Version - 2` download package for `order id #101` instead id `Version  - 1`.

Is this option is possible in magento CE 1.7.0.0?

Right now order id #101 is only having Version -1 package for download in customers downloadable page.

But we need to package file for each purchased orders?

Please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I place the following code into a .php script in the Magento root. You can call it via the CRON or your web browser.

```
<?php

    require('app/Mage.php');
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();

    $select = getDb()->select()
        ->from(getTable('downloadable/link'), array('link_id', 'link_file', 'product_id'));

    if (($links = getDb()->fetchAll($select)) !== false) {
        foreach($links as $link) {
            $linkId = $link['link_id'];
            $productId = $link['product_id'];
            $file = $link['link_file'];

            $select = getDb()->select()
                ->from(getTable('downloadable/link_title'), 'title')
                ->where('link_id=?', $linkId)
                ->limit(1);

            $title = getDb()->fetchOne($select);

            echo sprintf("Updating %s to %s<br />", $file, $title);

            $cond = getDb()->quoteInto('product_id=?', $productId);

            getDb()->update(getTable('downloadable/link_purchased_item'), array('link_id' =>$linkId,'link_title'=>$title,'link_file'=>$file), $cond);
        }
    }

    function getDb($conn = 'core_read') {
        return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($conn);
    }

    function getTable($table) {
        return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($table);
    }
```

Comment: Your Code help me lot!, Very Thanks Ben.

Comment: This code worked for me until I had a product with multiple downloadable files. I changed the condition in the code to the following and now it works:

`$cond = array();
$cond[] = getDb()->quoteInto('product_id=?', $productId);
$cond[] = getDb()->quoteInto('link_id=?', $linkId);`

Answer (score 2):

Although an old post, with an accepted answer, I will post another answer as an alternative solution.

To solve my issue I created an extension that will update the past orders to any chnages made in a products downloadable information.

This includes:

1. just updating an existing downloadable entry (thus changing Link title and file to download)
2. adding any new files to the downloadable list (example adding patch files as time goes by)
3. removing existing entries

Any past order that has the product you are adjusting as a purchased item will then update its downloadable list of products to whatever you edited to.

available via github: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/UpdateDownloadLinks

Comment: Thanks for great free solution!

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by proxiblue is OK but is not complete.

The algorithm has also a bug, it always takes all the links of the product and delete the old ones. In this way the links are always renewed and the download statistic is lost. 
To fix this you should add the following code:

```
$currentPurchasedItemsT = $linkPurchasedItems->getItems();
$currentPurchasedItems=array();
foreach( $currentPurchasedItemsT as $c){
    $currentPurchasedItems[$c["link_id"]] = $c;
}
```

Another inconvenience is that all new links are added to all orders even if is paid or not. 
It's not OK that paid links are added by default to all orders, event if the customers have not paid for them.

```
$data = $newFile->getData();
if ($linkPurchased->getOrderItemId() && $data["price"]=="0.0000") {
```

The full code is :

```
class ProxiBlue_UpdateDownloadLinks_Model_Observer {
    public function catalog_product_save_after($observer) {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        return;
        if ($product->getTypeId() == Mage_Downloadable_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE) {
            // get all the purchased items that match the product
            $linkPurchasedItems = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $product->getId())->load();
            $currentPurchasedItemsT = $linkPurchasedItems->getItems();
            $currentPurchasedItems=array();
            foreach( $currentPurchasedItemsT as $c){
                $currentPurchasedItems[$c["link_id"]] = $c;
            }
        $files = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getLinks($product);
        //build a list of purchase objects (orders) that were used to buy this product
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $productId))
            ->load();
        $purchaseObjects = array();
        foreach($collection as $orderItem) {
            $purchaseObject = mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased')->load($orderItem->getOrderId(),'order_id');
            if($purchaseObject->getId()) {
                $purchaseObjects[$purchaseObject->getId()] = $purchaseObject;
            }    
        }
        //determine and add any new files to the orders that have the product

        $newFiles = array_diff_key($files, $currentPurchasedItems);


        foreach ($newFiles as $newFile) {
            //attach each new file to the purchase

            foreach ($purchaseObjects as $linkPurchased) {
                $data = $newFile->getData();

                if ($linkPurchased->getOrderItemId() && $data["price"]=="0.0000") {

                    $linkHash = strtr(base64_encode(microtime() . $linkPurchased->getId() . $linkPurchased->getOrderItemId()
                                    . $product->getId()), '+/=', '-_,');
                    $linkPurchasedItem = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item');
                    $linkPurchasedItem->setData($newFile->getData());
                    $linkPurchasedItem->unsItemId();                        
                    $linkPurchasedItem->setPurchasedId($linkPurchased->getId())
                            ->setOrderItemId($linkPurchased->getOrderItemId())
                            ->setLinkHash($linkHash)
                            ->setLinkTitle($newFile->getTitle())
                            ->setStatus(Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_AVAILABLE);
                            //->setUpdatedAt(now())
                    $linkPurchasedItem->save();
                }
            }
            //exit;
        }

        // determine what is no longer attached as files and remove from the download links
        $noLongerAttachedAsFiles = array_diff_key($currentPurchasedItems,$files);

        //var_dump(array_diff_key($currentPurchasedItems,$files));
        //echo "<br/><br/>";
        //exit;
        foreach ($noLongerAttachedAsFiles as $purchasedLink) {
            //$purchasedLink->delete();
        }

    }
}
```

}