# How to update several Downloadable Products and retain links for existing orders in 1.9

Tags: hyperlink, cron, cpanel, magento-1.9.1

Each time a Downloadable Product has been updated, the system changes the file name from

**dancing_happy_people.zip**

#### to

**dancing_happy_people_1.zip**

and customers who have purchased the original zip are not able to access the updated version.

I went into the **cPanel file manager** and deleted the obsolete versions and renamed the files (removing the "_1" ) but it made quite a mess and removed download links altogether.

Is there any way to restore links for the downloads to the customers' orders?
Is there any way to update links and retain the link to the customers' orders?

Many grateful thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Could this be a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27038352/9987367